# Delete rails items with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Cant delete item with AJAX

My application.js

```
    //= require rails-ujs
    //= require activestorage
    //= require turbolinks
    //= require jquery3
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require_tree .

    $('[data-js-task-id]').on("ajax:success", function(event, data, status, xhr){
        var task_id = xhr.responseJSON.id;
        $('[data-js-task-id=' + task_id + ']').hide();
   });
```

My index.html erb

```
     <li data-js-task-id=<%= task.id %> class="task">
                 <%= link_to task.title, task, class: "task-title text-dark ml-2" %>
                 <%= link_to '', task, remote: true, method: :delete, class:"far fa-trash-alt text-dark icon delete", title: "Delete" %>
    </li>
```

My task controller

```
    def destroy
         @task.destroy
         render json: @task
     end
```

Item delete with error, don't hide...

Comment: what error your getting? please post more details

Comment: _don't hide..._ ? What are you trying to say ?

Comment: Item not hide, i see them on screen, but in console i see that item deleted. If click on link again in console show error, that item not found

Comment: could you try with ` $(this).closest('li').fadeOut();`

Comment: DELETE http://localhost:3000/tasks 404 (Not Found)
Rails.ajax @ rails-ujs.self-d109d8c5c0194c8ad60b8838b2661c5596b5c955987f7cd4045eb2fb90ca5343.js?body=1:212
Rails.handleRemote @ rails-ujs.self-d109d8c5c0194c8ad60b8838b2661c5596b5c955987f7cd4045eb2fb90ca5343.js?body=1:568
(anonymous) @ rails-ujs.self-d109d8c5c0194c8ad60b8838b2661c5596b5c955987f7cd4045eb2fb90ca5343.js?body=1:169

Comment: try `respond_to do |format|
      format.js 
end ` instead of render json: @task

Comment: Thank you NEL!!!!

Comment: @MrUnknown glad it helped, could you please  accept my answer and upvote it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change this in your tasks controller

```
respond_to do |format|
 format.js 
end
```

instead of `render json: @task`